# WebRTC audio/video quality test using protractor using getUserMedia()

Tags: javascript, audio, video, protractor, webrtc

I'm trying to write a test in Protractor which can compute the quality of audio and video in a WebRTC session. So far, by using the `--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=sample.y4m` and `--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture=sampleAudio.wav`, I've been able to load the audio and video onto the WebRTC connection.

Forums suggest to use getUserMedia() to record the audio and video and compare them with original to get the PESQ score. (*don't know how to implement this*)

Has anyone went this path? If yes, can you suggest how I should go about this issue?